# Custom event doesn't log on Firebase Analytics Event Section

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have middle of Firebase of Custom Events integration. I am facing a problem that events which are register or log form my code those are not listed on dashboard.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Comapose_Message", parameters: [
            AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(420)",
            AnalyticsParameterItemName: "Test",
            AnalyticsParameterContentType: "Test"
            ])
```

I am working on swift 4.0. I wait for more than 4 hours but it does not reflect over dashboard.

Dashboard still showing default events. Can any one help me out why event not showing here???

[image: Firebase Event Dashboard]board.

Comment: Can you please turn on the Debug mode to see whether your events make it to the Debug View (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)?